# How to direct from post to category page in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on my Django blog. I have a trouble to redirect from post to category, when you open post you can click to category and when you click on category I want you to redirect you to category and show posts only from that category.

This part of my html code for post_detail.html

```
<div class="entry-meta meta-0 font-small mb-30"><a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}"><span class="post-cat bg-success color-white">{{ post.category}}</span></a></div>
<h1 class="post-title mb-30">
    {{ post.post_title }}
</h1>
```

This is models.py only class category

```
class Category(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Updated at")
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Category name")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category_detail', args=[self.slug])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['category_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

in post_detail is defined like this (short view)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Title")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title
```

This is views.py

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
    latest_posts =  Post.objects.filter(created_at__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('created_at')[:9]
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

    context = {'post': post, 'latest_posts': latest_posts}
    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', context)


def category_detail(request, pk):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=pk)

    return render(request, 'category_detail.html', {'category': category})
```

This is urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.category_detail, name='category_detail'),
]
```

Any idea why I'm not redirected to category_detail page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all edit your Post model and add related_name option to category field.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Title")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title
```

now in your category detail template you can access Posts related to that category:

in category_detail.html:

```
{% for post in category.posts.all %}
{{ post.post_title }}
{% endfor %}
```

and you need to edit your post_detail.html:
change `{{ category.get_absolute_url }}` to `{{ post.category.get_absolute_url }}`

```
<div class="entry-meta meta-0 font-small mb-30"><a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}"><span class="post-cat bg-success color-white">{{ post.category}}</span></a></div>
<h1 class="post-title mb-30">
    {{ post.post_title }}
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks... Now I'm directed to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/`. But I got error to in my browser, `Page not found (404)  No Post matches the given query.`.  Using the URLconf defined in core.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
`admin/`
`[name='home']`
`<slug:slug>/ [name='post_detail']`
The current path, `category/`, matched the last one.

Comment: In your category_detail view you need to use slug instead of pk.

Comment: Thanks, but still same :/

Comment: Can I see your post  view?

Comment: Yes, please see question, it's edited

Comment: mdev, I recomend you upload your poject in your github account and give me its link. it seems youre new in django, I'll help you. You also can see real world django project ls in my github account. https://github.com/amirhamiri

Comment: Yes, I'm new but I'm not allowed to post the project. Thank you for the help. I'll see your github.

Comment: Ok you can text me in telegram @amirhamiri